# What is the best way to multiply this code all together instead of individually multiplying each one?

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to make a math program that can multiply three variables at once, and i don't know the best way to do that

```
 Console.WriteLine("Input your x");
        var g = Console.ReadLine();
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(g);

        Console.WriteLine("Input your y");
        var f = Console.ReadLine();
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(f);

        Console.WriteLine("Input your z");
        var l = Console.ReadLine();
        int z = Convert.ToInt32(l);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z}");           
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that code is relevant as such, can you show us your inputs and what exactly you want output

Comment: Something like: `Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z}\t = " + x * y * z);`

Comment: Yea,      Console.WriteLine("Input your x");
            var g = Console.ReadLine();
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(g);

            Console.WriteLine("Input your y");
            var f = Console.ReadLine();
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(f);

            Console.WriteLine("Input your z");
            var l = Console.ReadLine();
            int z = Convert.ToInt32(l);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z}");           
            Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Yes, that works thank you very much

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Multiplying result: " + x*y*z);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the Math function inline then you can do this

```
Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z} = {x * y * z}");
```

And if you would prefer to have a variable stored

```
int m = x * y * z;
Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z} = {m}");
```

Comment: That works but how can i multiply the whole thing by a variable like.          Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z}\t" + a(x * y * z));

Comment: In that situation you use the `*` operator again, like so  `Console.WriteLine($"{x}\t{y}\t{z}\t" + a * (x * y * z));`. Because the `x* y* z` is in brackets, you can still use the `*` (which means multiply)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you use C# 6.0

```
 Console.WriteLine($"{x} * {y} * {z} = {x * y * z}");
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} * {1} * {2} = {3}", x, y, z, x * y * z));
```